# How to reopen a closed ticket using the Zendesk API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, zendesk, zendesk-api

My objective is to reopen a closed Zendesk ticket through the [Zendesk API](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/tickets.html#description-and-first-comment).

I tried to update the field "open" through

```
https://support.XXXXXX.com/api/v2/tickets/XXXXX.json
```

and got the response:

```
{
    "error"       => "RecordInvalid", 
    "description" => "Record validation errors", 
    "details"     => {
        "status" => [
            {
                "description" => "Statut : the status Close prevent the ticket update"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a solution, or do I have to open a new ticket?

I am actually using the "[Official Ruby Zendesk API Client](https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb)", but the issue is in the API side so it is not related to the gem.

I will send a ticket to Zendesk support also, but I hoped someone on Stack Overflow might have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not reopen a ticket that was closed.

The documentation is "[Creating follow-up tickets](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/tickets.html#creating-follow-up-tickets)". In the API  you can also find details of how to create a follow-up ticket:

```
curl https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json \
  -d '{"ticket": {"via_followup_source_id": 103, "comment": {"body": "my message"}}}' \
  -v -u {email_address}:{password} -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive link text than "here". See these pages: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)".
"[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
"[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)"